# Ionic push notifications on Android doesn't register token on Ionic.io

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to implement push notification on Android using ionic.

I've followed the documentation from Ionic push in a tutorial from devdactic [Devdactic push notifications android](https://devdactic.com/android-push-notifications/)  I see with that example in the platform is saved a token.

I've make all settings that I need including GCM service and register user to ionic platform, but no token is registered.

I run app in emulator and user is registered but no token is saved. After some modifiers I receive a token in console but is not ok.

In example token is different and push does't work. Does someone have an working example with Ionic Push based on last documentation?

Comment: but no token is registered ???

Comment: USer is registered but doesn't have asociated a token.User has no push tokens registered. This is the message in the platform

Comment: I've tried a lot of things but no result

Comment: you are talking about current user device id am i right

Comment: On Ionic.io platform when you register a user you have more fields.In a example from devdactic android push notification there a token is saved on section PUSH.You can watch this tutorial and if you have time to try it.I wait for your answer. https://devdactic.com/android-push-notifications/

Comment: to send a push notification you need 1).  **senderid** 2). GCM **API key** 3). **current device token** so you have all this 3 things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109776/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-aleleee).

Comment: I have sender id..i have gcm api key...but on android how i obtain device token ?

Answer (score 1):

this is what I use to register pushes, it is messy but hopefully can be of some use. It checks if the current user is authenticated, if they aren't then it signs them up with a UUID (i used a UUID generator plugin) and saves the token. Just make sure your app is set up with Ionic.io and this should work :)

```
var user = Ionic.User.current();

if (user.isAuthenticated()) {

            var push = new Ionic.Push({
                "debug": true,
                "onNotification": function (notification) {                        
                },
                "onRegister": function (data) {
                    console.log(data.token);
                    return true;
                },
                "pluginConfig": {
                    "android": {
                        "icon": "icon"
                    },
                    "ios": {
                        "badge": true,
                        "sound": true,
                        "alert": true
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {


            var uid = uuid2.newuuid();

            var details = {
                'email': uid + '@example.com',
                'password': 'secretpassword'
            };

            Ionic.Auth.signup(details).then(function () {
                var options = { 'remember': true };
                Ionic.Auth.login('basic', options, details).then(function () {
                    user = Ionic.User.current();
                    user.set('uid', uid);
                    user.save();

                    var push = new Ionic.Push({
                        "debug": true,
                        "onNotification": function (notification) {                                
                        },
                        "onRegister": function (data) {
                            console.log(data.token);
                            return true;
                        },
                        "pluginConfig": {
                            "android": {
                                "icon": "icon"
                            },
                            "ios": {
                                "badge": true,
                                "sound": true,
                                "alert": true
                            }
                        }
                    });


                    push.register(function (token) {
                        console.log("Device token:", token.token);
                        push.saveToken(token);
                    });
                }, function () { });
            }, function () { });

        }
```

Comment: this works for you? i mean...you save the token on ionic.io ?

Comment: Just solve this by adding gcm project number to iobic.io.config  ionic config set gcm_key <your gcm project key>

Answer (score 0):

In order to send push notification you need Api key and project number and current device id.

I think you are struggling in getting the user device id in order to get the current your device id please reffer [ng-Cordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/)

you can find a line

```
 $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification)
```

in this you can see the **notification** parameter  it is an object inside that object you can find `regid` field in that you can get your current device id this will be work on only mobile not on browser.

so in order to use that device id, for example lets assume your going to post a login form with divece id like given below.

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
          console.log(event);
          console.log(notification);

          switch(notification.event) {
            case 'registered':
            console.log(notification.regid.length);
              if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
               // alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
               console.log('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
                 var loginPost = {
                    "UserName":username,
                    "PassWord":password,
                    "DeviceID":notification.regid
                  };
                  console.log(loginPost);
```