# push notification using ionic and php with clear example

Tags: php, ionic-framework

I'm new in ionic framework.

I need to implement push notification in my mobile Application using ionic with google GCM (Back end as PHP) .

I spend lot of time and hence I getting error only. So, i need one clear example with php.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762552/ionic-push-notifications-on-android-doesnt-register-token-on-ionic-io/36765094#36765094 check my answers for android push notification

Comment: i am not sure about php back end push but for front end please refer this answer

Answer (score 0):

For Front End see [Here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/)

For Backend get your API_ACCESS_KEY an send a curl request to GCM. See below code

```
// API_ACCESS_KEY you can get it from your google account 
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaSyA_XXXXXXXvXXXXxxxxxxXXXX');
    $msg = array
    (
    'message' => 'YOUR MESSAGE',
    'title' => 'YOUR TITLE',
    'vibrate' => 1,
    'sound' => 1

    // you can also add images, additionalData
    );
     // registration ids are registered device ids
     $registrationIds =['ID1',ID2];
    $fields = array
    (
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
    'data' => $msg
    );
    $headers = array
    (
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
```

Comment: i need frontend more detail...Ionic frontend not working properly..device token changing every second