# Push notification not showing in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm doing push notification in ionic framework. I getting only alert. I need to get notification.

My javascript code

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic',  'ionic.service.core','ngCordova', 'ionic.service.push'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(['$ionicAppProvider', function($ionicAppProvider) {
  $ionicAppProvider.identify({
    app_id: '38676e5c',
    api_key: '76e051384cb6095e751db3791e26b2bd1162cceccd039f2a',
    dev_push: true
  });
}])

.controller('PushCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicUser, $ionicPush) {

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:tokenReceived', function(event, data) {
    alert('Success: ' + data.token);
    console.log('name: ' + data.token + "--- Id: ");
    console.log('Got token: ' , data.token, data.platform);
    $scope.token = data.token;
  });

  $scope.identifyUser = function() {
    var user = $ionicUser.get();

    if (!user.user_id) {
      user.user_id = $ionicUser.generateGUID();
    }

    angular.extend(user, {
      name: 'My Name',
      bio: 'I am awesome'
    });

    $ionicUser.identify(user).then(function() {
      $scope.identified = true;
      console.log('name: ' + user.name + "--- Id: " + user.user_id);
    });
  };

  $scope.pushRegister = function() {
    $ionicPush.register({
      canShowAlert: true,
      canSetBadge: true,
      canPlaySound: true,
      canRunActionsOnWake: true,
      onNotification: function(notification) {
        // handle your stuff
        return true;
      }
    });
  };
});
```

**my server code**

```
curl -u b81bb9cdc8ed06236804524c8e9b59ccc001900cd22f3c65: -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Ionic-Application-Id: 38676e5c" https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push -d '{"tokens": ["DEV-83f6de08-18fc-4bd9-9acd-72f974c2958a"],"production": false, "notification":{ "alert":"asasdsasd", "title": "demo", "android": {"payload": {"title": "hello","message": "hello"}}, "ios": {"payload": {"title": "hello","message": "hello"}}}}'
```

**My output**

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbux7.png)

**My problem is**

I only getting alert(not notification)
  Device token changing every second..

**What i need ??**

1. I need to get push notification in notification bar..
2. I need unique device token..(id)..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762552/ionic-push-notifications-on-android-doesnt-register-token-on-ionic-io/36765094#36765094 check this out stack question and look the tutorial here https://devdactic.com/android-push-notifications/

Comment: inorder to get the device token refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717556/retrieve-the-device-token-from-device-using-ionic-framework/36717874#36717874

Comment: thank you @mohan ...i tried that also ..it's throw this error "Ionic.User.anonymousId(); is undefined" ,and set some dummy number as userid.it won't create user in ionic.io..if u got output please send that package to me( balakumaran.raji@gmail.com)

Comment: in your question  you asked you need device token the stack overflow as the solution and then to get ionic push notification you need api and sederid  then what is your error

Comment: See my output ...i receive my notification as alert format..i didn't receive notification...that's my problem..i tried all method i didn't get any output

Comment: then i think its backend issues normaly when a GCM msg recived then it will show as notification if app is in close if app is in open then it will show in alert

Comment: i using google GCM project number as senderID it's correct!!

Comment: It's show when app is open...if app close it won't work..nothing happen...

Comment: yes correct project number as **senderid** and **api server key** of that project is need, and in you gcm account check weather **API mangaer credetial is enabled or not(it should be enabled)**

Comment: Yes i enabled it...shall i send my code in ur mailid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one in your ionic app.js controller

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

       //Ionic.io();
      var push = new Ionic.Push({
        "debug": true
      });

      push.register(function(token) {
        console.log(token);
        console.log("Device token:",token.token);
        tokenapp = token.token;
        console.log(tokenapp);
      });

  });
})
```

Comment: it throwing  "Error: Ionic is not defined"

Comment: have you registere your sender id and serverkey to your current project document

Comment: like this **ionic push --google-api-key your-google-api-key,
ionic config set gcm_key your-gcm-project-number,
ionic config set dev_push false**

Comment: i have send a mail send your project as a zip file i will check it send me sederid and api server key also to that mail

Comment: sorry i did not recive any one

Comment: i sent it from balakumaran.g@infinitisoftware.net

Comment: i did not get any mail